# Prefill the input boxes of a list based upon lookup

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, custom-list

I had a list say company that contains columns like CompanyName.

Then another list called as Addresses contains a lookup to conmpany and additional columns like Street, City

What i need to do is to create a another list where i will select the company address and some of the columns like Street, City of lookup tables is copied using say "Validation" into the columns of this list.

E.g.  Address has Addr1, Street1, CIty1

when i select this address i want thes values are copies into the new list textboxes which can i overrride.

Is this possible and do you have any sample. I want to prefer the easiest way.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Create a seperate list to hold all cities and associated addresses. Then add a lookup column that points to the new list.  You can configure the lookup column to do exactly what you need. [Check here for an example](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/lookup-columns-in-sharepoint-2010.html)